# current sense switch

Tags: schematics

This schematic triggers the relay when current exceeds 1-3A:

[image: schematic]

I want to do some modification in this circuit;

How can i reverse the circuit working to trigger the relay when power connected to INPUT and disconnect it when current exceed the set point?

How can i decrease the minimum current set point from 1A to 500ma or lower?

Also i couldn't find IC CA3140 but the seller said CA3130 should work, appreciate it if someone confirm this.

[CA3140 datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/ca3140-a.pdf)

[CA3130 datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/ca3130-a.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i reverse the circuit working to trigger the relay when power connected to INPUT and disconnect it when current exceed the set point?

Either -

1. The circuit has a changeover relay. Wire supply to the common terminal and load to the normally open or normally closed as required.
2. Swap pins 2 and 3 of U1.

> How can i decrease the minimum current set point from 1A to 500ma or lower?

Adjust PR1 to the correct sensitivity.

> Also i couldn't find IC CA3140 but the seller said CA3130 should work, appreciate it if someone confirm this.

Both seem to run off a 5 V supply, if that's what you're worried about. The CA3130 should work.

Comment: so PR1 adjust the set current from 0 to 3A not 1-3A right?

Comment: R1 appears to be 0.1 Ω so the voltage drop across it will be 0.1 V per ampere running through it. R3 and R6 set the non-inverting input to half supply. R2, PR1 and R6 perform a similar but adjustable function for the inverting input. You can set it as close as you like. A 10-turn pot might help. Alternately scale up R1 by the same factor you are scaling down the current.